# How to observe didEnterFullScreenNotification globally?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I want to observer `NSWindow.didEnterFullScreenNotification` globally trigger by all app. How to do it?

Background Info

I am marking a watermark security app, but it doesn't work when any app enter full screen mode, and it works when other app out of full screen mode, so my solutions as following:

1. Observer `NSWindow.didEnterFullScreenNotification` globally, if I receive any notification, then I send data to the server.

```
// NotificationCenter.default.addObserver Can only observe within my watermark app
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.didEnterFullScreenNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { (noti) in
  print("didEnterFullScreenNotification")

 }
```

2. Let this watermark app, always in front of other windows. But is that any way to achieve this?
   3.`NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents` seems like there is a window property there, but still don't know what to do
3. I has attached a screenshot for your references, it is my watermark app.

Comment: have tried with `NSNotificationCenter addObserver`?

Comment: Thanks i tried ,NSNotificationCenter addObserver can only observe within my app

Answer (score 1):

There only notifications you can observe "globally" are ones posted to NSDistributedNotificationCenter. All of the usual notifications you see in Cocoa APIs are posted only to the app's internal / "local" notification center.

You can see which global notifications are posted by adding an observer and passing `nil` for the name and object. You can then log the name of the received notifications. The only notification that fires when a window goes full screen is `NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification` but that simply means the space changed; there's no way to know it was because a window became full screen.